# Angular Attributes Not recognized by Day CQ Link Checker Transformer

Tags: angularjs, apache, aem, sling

I am using "Day CQ Link Checker Transformer" for URL mapping on a project,
yet I need to transform a link on a button based on angularJS.
But when I try to add `Data-navurl` on Day CQ Link Checker Transformer,
it does not transform the URL on the web page.

Comment: Have you checked, that a <a href="same-link-as-for-angularjs">xx</a> is transformed correctly? If yes, then you should post your configuration and the not-transformed html-snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The Link Checker Transformer will not work for Angular applications as your markup is contained within `<script>` tags. You will need to force the rewriting of the url using a JSP tag library or HTL Sling Model.

UPDATE:

To explain further... the `LinkCheckerTransformer` works just like any other transformer in the [Sling rewriting pipeline](http://sling.apache.org/site/rewriting-the-output-through-pipelines.html), it responds to SAX events from the HTML parser. This means that it may not rewrite all links within your HTML page unless it is configured to generate an event. For example, `<input>` tags may be used to hold open redirects – these will not be rewritten unless the `INPUT` tag is added to the HTML parser and `input:value` is added to the list of rewrite elements. You can try to add `SCRIPT` tags to the HTML parser but I'm not sure how the parsing would behave...

Comment: Following is the code snippet
<button type="button" data-navurl="/content/mysite/en/home/test.html" class="btn btn-default" ng-click=navigate("/content/mysite/en/home/test.html")>SUBMIT</button>

Day CQ Link Checker Transformer :-
Rewrite Elements==>button:data-navurl

@mickleroy

Comment: @sohumwahi your button is irrelevant in the context of a `<script>` tag (i.e. Angular template). I've updated my answer to explain why...

Comment: @sohumwahi let me know if you want information on modifying the html parser (but I can't guarantee it will work)

Answer (score 1):

`Day CQ Link Checker Transformer` does not check anything on the `text` level of XML DOM structure. It treats HTML as an XML document and rules are only applied to elements and attributes.

In your case the angular template is part of a `<script>` element but it is treated as a text and therefore it is skipped.

This is no different from writing a normal JS to inject a link in your page. Link checker will gracefully ignore the script text.